# Git merge. Behavior different on explicit merge than on pull

Tags: linux, git

I have a problem with my git configuration. I like to use the `--no-ff` option when I merge two branch. So I put on my configuration file `~/.gitconfig` under the section `[merge]` the option `ff = no`. Which set the no fast forward behavior by default.

But now my problem is that when I do a git pull, it create a new commit (and merge) even if there's no modification. So i'm obliged to specify `--ff` on the pull command... Which is the same than specify `--no-ff` on the merge.

Is there a way to configure separately each of there two command ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: From http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Use-quot-git-pull-ff-only-quot-by-default-td5084103.html, I don't think is is obvious to do.